# Count of distinct records - SQL

Tags: sql, db2

```
empid   projectId   TaskID
100     500           1
100     501           1
100     502           1
101     500           2
101     500          5
101     500          1
102     400          1
103     300          2
104     300          2
105     300          2
```

I am trying to list the employees who works on multiple project only,  based on project id .
I tried distinct and GROUP BY . but am not able figure it exactly.

from the above table am expecting a result like this

```
 empid   projectId  
    100     500         
    100     501          
    100     502
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this *(revised code)*

```
SELECT DISTINCT EmpId, ProjectId
FROM TableX
WHERE EmpId IN 
(
    SELECT EmpId
    FROM TableX
    GROUP BY EmpId
    HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT ProjectId) > 1
)
```

This should give you

```
EmpId       ProjectId
----------- -----------
100         500
100         501
100         502

3 row(s)
```

**Edit** Content added for OPs additional question in the comments

A count giving you distint ProjectIds would mean that the GROUP BY would be at an `EmpId` level and no need for a subquery

```
SELECT EmpId, Count (Distinct ProjectId) Projects
FROM TableX
GROUP BY EmpId
```

To get a count of projects for all employees with multiple projects, do the following

```
SELECT EmpId, Count (Distinct ProjectId) Projects
FROM TableX
GROUP BY EmpId
Having Count (Distinct ProjectId) > 1
```

Comment: Do you want a `COUNT` of tasks?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a windowed `COUNT()`:

```
WITH counted AS (
  SELECT
    empid,
    projectId,
    COUNT(DISTINCT projectId) OVER (PARTITION BY empid) AS ProjectCount
  FROM atable
)
SELECT DISTINCT
  empid,
  projectId
FROM counted
WHERE ProjectCount > 1
```

References:

- [OLAP functions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0000736.htm)
- [WITH clause](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0000879.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT y.empid, y.projectId
    FROM (SELECT empid
              FROM YourTable
              GROUP BY empid
              HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t
        INNER JOIN YourTable y
            ON t.empid = y.empid
    ORDER BY y.empid, y.projectId
```

Comment: You really do not need to join in this case.

Comment: @MariusSolbakkenMellum Can you show us how you do this without a JOIN?

Comment: Sorry, little quick on the trigger here. Did a little misread and mixed up with another open question..